# I use 1/2 cup shortening and 1/2 cup butter in baking chocolate chips cookies but they always fall flat

Tags: cookies

Unless I put pecans in my chocolate chip cookies they always fall flat when I take them out of the oven.  What do I need to do for them to stand up.

Comment: Can you tell us the full recipe? Is it the classic chocolate chip cookie recipe (e.g. [this copy](http://www.verybestbaking.com/recipes/18476/Original-NESTL%C3%89-TOLL-HOUSE-Chocolate-Chip-Cookies/detail.aspx)) except with some butter replaced with shortening?

Comment: And what do you mean by "fall flat"--is it actually happening visibly when you remove them from the oven?  It is normal for cookies to deflate some as they are removed from the oven if they are not cooked to the point of being completely crisp.  Moister softer cookies will naturally settle a bit.

Comment: The most common fixes for flat cookies are to cream the butter/shortening for a really long time (longer than you think) and to use fresh leavener.  But we can help you a lot more if you expand on your recipe and process.

Comment: And tell us what is different with and without pecans....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to buy a new box of baking soda or baking powder?
Baking soda & baking powder can & do lose 'oomph' over time.

Otherwise try chilling the dough for at least 4 hours before baking.
Chilling the dough usually helps butter/shortening based cookies hold their form a tad bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Just use butter flavored Crisco instead of both and make sure your batter isn't too thin. You should be able to ball some up and hold that form.

Comment: But people make chocolate chip cookies with just butter all the time without them being too flat - why would you have to use shortening? And if the dough is too soft, what do you suggest changing?